# How to update users regarding newer version of iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I am going to upload my app at app store, n will have to upload next version of app after some time, how i can update to users regarding newer version of app?

should i implement push notification or apple will take care of this?

Answer (score 1):

If your app already has support for push notifications, you can send out a notification, but it's to late if your app is published without a push notification implementation.

When your new version of the app is accepted and published by the App Store, the App Store will notify your users that an update is available.  Don't bother with push notifications just for telling your users that a new version is available.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Berna.

if anyone wants more information regarding this, see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551918/iphone-managing-version-updates-of-a-native-app